# org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save()

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am tryinf to use `SERIAL` type for id generation of a table. But in this case I am getting an exception it says that I need to save the id before. I have another table like this but that one is working fine.

JPA Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pay_appln_data",
        uniqueConstraints = {
                @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"dept_ref_no", "application_no"})
                })
public class PayApplnData {
    
    @Id 
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(name = "dept_ref_no")
    private String deptRefNo;
    
    @Column(name = "application_no")
    private String applicationNo;
    
    @Column(name = "depositor_name")
    private String depositorName;
    ...
    ...
}
```

SQL for the table used:

```
CREATE TABLE public.pay_appln_data
(
    id serial NOT NULL,
    dept_ref_no character varying(16) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    application_no character varying(30) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    depositor_name character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    ...
    ...
    ...
    CONSTRAINT pay_appln_data_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT unique_key UNIQUE (dept_ref_no, application_no)
)
```

The sequence presemt in DB is:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE public.pay_appln_data_id_seq
    INCREMENT 1
    START 1
    MINVALUE 1
    MAXVALUE 2147483647
    CACHE 1;

ALTER SEQUENCE public.pay_appln_data_id_seq
    OWNER TO postgres;
```

The exception thrown is:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): com.rent.mngWithAdmin.model.GRIPSRentPayApplnData; nested exception is org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): com.rent.mngWithAdmin.model.GRIPSRentPayApplnData
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:353)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:255)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:528)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
    at com.rent.mngWithAdmin.DAO.GRIPSRentPayApplnDataDAOImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4516a353.saveOrUpdate(<generated>)
    at com.rent.mngWithAdmin.service.GRIPSApplicationDataServiceImpl.saveOrUpdate(GRIPSApplicationDataServiceImpl.java:21)
    at com.rent.mngWithAdmin.controller.GRIPSRentPayController.rentPayDetails(GRIPSRentPayController.java:301)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): com.rent.mngWithAdmin.model.GRIPSRentPayApplnData
    at org.hibernate.id.Assigned.generate(Assigned.java:33)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.saveTransientEntity(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:271)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:791)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:778)
    at com.rent.mngWithAdmin.DAO.GRIPSRentPayApplnDataDAOImpl.saveOrUpdate(GRIPSRentPayApplnDataDAOImpl.java:22)
    at com.rent.mngWithAdmin.DAO.GRIPSRentPayApplnDataDAOImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$4bee3df2.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    ... 56 more
2021-05-04 12:50:31.403 DEBUG 616 --- [nio-3030-exec-5] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select tbl.next_val from hibernate_sequences tbl where tbl.sequence_name=? for update of tbl
2021-05-04 12:50:31.406 DEBUG 616 --- [nio-3030-exec-5] org.hibernate.SQL                        : update hibernate_sequences set next_val=?  where next_val=? and sequence_name=?
2021-05-04 12:50:31.455 DEBUG 616 --- [nio-3030-exec-5] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select tbl.next_val from hibernate_sequences tbl where tbl.sequence_name=? for update of tbl
2021-05-04 12:50:31.456 DEBUG 616 --- [nio-3030-exec-5] org.hibernate.SQL                        : update hibernate_sequences set next_val=?  where next_val=? and sequence_name=?
```

I couldn't understand that why it is searching in the `hibernate_sequences` whereas I am using `SERIAL` type for it's id?

Thnaks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the Sequence you created for the ID generation.

This can be done with the following annotation:

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "pay_appln_data_id_seq", sequenceName = "pay_appln_data_id_seq")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = SEQUENCE, generator = "pay_appln_data_id_seq")
private Long id;
```